How do i prevent class-transformer from changing my _id from Mongodb?
So, my task was to prevent the password field from being sent to the response after handling the request. For this, I've found this interceptor implementation
export type ClassConstructor = new (...args: any[]) => object;

export class SerializeInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private dto: ClassConstructor) {}
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, handler: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return handler.handle().pipe(
      map((data: ClassConstructor) => {
        return plainToClass(this.dto, data, {
          excludeExtraneousValues: true,
          exposeUnsetFields: false,
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}

now, to use it i just made the decorator for it
export function Serialize(dto: ClassConstructor) {
  return UseInterceptors(new SerializeInterceptor(dto));
}

here is an example of use in one of the controllers
  @Serialize(LoginResponseDto)
  @Post('registration')
  registration(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return this.authService.registration(createUserDto);
  }

the Dto I use is like this
export class UserEntity {
  @Expose()
  _id: string;
  @Expose()
  firstName: string;
  @Expose()
  lastName: string;
  @Expose()
  email: string;
}

export class LoginResponseDto {
  @Expose()
  @Type(() => UserEntity)
  user: UserEntity;

  @Expose()
  accessToken: string;

  @Expose()
  refreshToken: string;
}

so, the problem is when I run the registration or login I do not need to return the the password. it works, now I don't get the password, but my _id value in the response changes every time.
Response body:
{
    "user": {
        "_id": "66d8223e932f4803a4d3810e", --wrong _id value
        "firstName": "name",
        "lastName": "last",
        "email": "email"
    },
    "accessToken": "accessToekn",
    "refreshToken": "refreshToken"
}

the value I need to get: 66d81d858c7066f3b63fb21d.
The id change is because of this option in the interceptor: excludeExtraneousValues: true,
without it the _id field doesn't change but now I get responses like this:
{
    "user": {
        "$__": {
            "activePaths": {
                "paths": {
                    "password": "init",
                    "email": "init",
                    "lastName": "init",
                    "firstName": "init",
                    "_id": "init",
                    "__v": "init"
                },
                "states": {
                    "require": {},
                    "init": {
                        "_id": true,
                        "firstName": true,
                        "lastName": true,
                        "email": true,
                        "password": true,
                        "__v": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "skipId": true
        },
        "$isNew": false,
        "_doc": {
            "_id": "66d81d858c7066f3b63fb21d", --doesn't change
            "firstName": "first",
            "lastName": "last",
            "email": "email",
            "password": "password",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "_id": "66d81d858c7066f3b63fb21d", --doesn't change
        "firstName": "fisrt",
        "lastName": "last",
        "email": "email"
    },
    "accessToken": "token",
    "refreshToken": "token"
}

Maybe I need to change something in the model?
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';

export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>;

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  firstName: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  lastName: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  password: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

I am actually lost, if anybody has the answer to it, I would appreciate it.
I've tried to give the _id prop in the LoginResopnseDto the @Transform(value=>value.obj._id.toString()) when the flag that changes the _id is true, but it works only sometimes, and most of the time it won't

You may try to convert the User model by using the data.toJson() method in the SerializeInterceptor. Let's see if it fixes it.
